# jQuery Steps con 5 pasos

Tags: jquery

Alguien ha hecho que "jQuery Steps wizard plugin(http://www.jquery-steps.com/)" funcione con más de 5 pasos? Lo que he podido hacer es poner los 5 pasos pero cuando se presiona el botón "Siguiente en el paso 4 no avanza al paso 5, si le doy click directamente al tab si  se muestra lo del paso 5.

Modifique el "stepwizard.css":

```
.wizard > .steps > ul > li
{
    width: 25%;
}
```

a:

```
.wizard > .steps > ul > li
{
    width: 20%;
}
```

No se si tengo que modificar algo en la librería js.

La configuración que tengo es la siguiente:

```
var settings = {
/* Appearance */
headerTag: "h1",
bodyTag: "div",
contentContainerTag: "div",
actionContainerTag: "div",
stepsContainerTag: "div",
cssClass: "wizard",
stepsOrientation: $.fn.steps.stepsOrientation.horizontal,

/* Templates */
titleTemplate: '<span class="number">#index#.</span> #title#',
loadingTemplate: '<span class="spinner"></span> #text#',

/* Behaviour */
autoFocus: false,
enableAllSteps: true,
enableKeyNavigation: true,
enablePagination: true,
suppressPaginationOnFocus: true,
enableContentCache: true,
enableCancelButton: false,
enableFinishButton: true,
preloadContent: false,
showFinishButtonAlways: false,
forceMoveForward: false,
saveState: false,
startIndex: 0,

/* Transition Effects */
transitionEffect: $.fn.steps.transitionEffect.none,
transitionEffectSpeed: 200,
labels: {
        cancel: "Cancelar",
        current: "current step:",
        pagination: "Pagination",
        finish: "Cerrar",
        next: "Siguiente",
        previous: "Anterior",
        loading: "Cargando ..."
    }
};
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código HTML, aqui solo puse los encabezados de los 5 pasos, nopuse el código html del contenido de cada paso:

```
<form id="frmSolicitud" method="post">
<div id="welcome">
    <div id="stepsWizard">
        <input type="hidden" id="idSolicitud" value=@ViewBag.Id>
        
        <h1>Cliente</h1>
        <div style="height:500px; width:100%; overflow:auto;">
                        </div>

        <h1>Comodatos</h1>
        <div style="height:500px; width:100%; overflow:auto;">
            
        </div>

        <h1>Recuperación de Inversión</h1>
        <div style="height:500px; width:100%; overflow:auto;">
            
        </div>

     <h1>Requisición Compra</h1>
        <div style="height:500px; width:100%; overflow:auto;">
            
        </div>

        <h1>Documentos</h1>
        <div style="height:500px; width:100%; overflow:auto;">
            
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: podrías incluir el código html?

Comment: ya edite la pregunta con el codigo html

Comment: La verdad es que no logro replicar la falla. ¿Existe algún script o algo que no estén incluyendo en la pregunta? ¿Podrías subir tu código en un simulador?

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como lo hice yo alguna vez, espero te sirva

```js
var form = $("#signup-form");
    form.steps({
        headerTag: "h3",
        bodyTag: "fieldset",
        transitionEffect: "fade",
        labels: {
            previous: 'Anterior',
            next: 'Siguiente',
            finish: 'Finalizar',
            current: ''
        },
        titleTemplate: '<h3 class="title">#title#</h3>',
        onFinished: function(event, currentIndex) {
            alert('Sumited');
        },
    });
```

```css
/* @extend display-flex; */
display-flex, .signup-content, .actions ul, .actions ul li a {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex; }

/* @extend list-type-ulli; */
list-type-ulli, .actions ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

/* poppins-300 - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-300.eot");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local("Poppins Light"), local("Poppins-Light"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-300.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-300.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-300.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-300.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-300.svg#Poppins") format("svg");
  /* Legacy iOS */ }
/* poppins-300italic - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-300italic.eot");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local("Poppins Light Italic"), local("Poppins-LightItalic"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-300italic.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-300italic.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-300italic.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-300italic.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-300italic.svg#Poppins") format("svg");
  /* Legacy iOS */ }
/* poppins-regular - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-regular.eot");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local("Poppins Regular"), local("Poppins-Regular"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-regular.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-regular.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-regular.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-regular.svg#Poppins") format("svg");
  /* Legacy iOS */ }
/* poppins-italic - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-italic.eot");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local("Poppins Italic"), local("Poppins-Italic"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-italic.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-italic.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-italic.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-italic.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-italic.svg#Poppins") format("svg");
  /* Legacy iOS */ }
/* poppins-500 - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-500.eot");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local("Poppins Medium"), local("Poppins-Medium"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-500.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-500.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-500.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-500.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-500.svg#Poppins") format("svg");
  /* Legacy iOS */ }
/* poppins-500italic - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-500italic.eot");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local("Poppins Medium Italic"), local("Poppins-MediumItalic"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-500italic.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-500italic.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-500italic.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-500italic.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-500italic.svg#Poppins") format("svg");
  /* Legacy iOS */ }
/* poppins-600 - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-600.eot");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local("Poppins SemiBold"), local("Poppins-SemiBold"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-600.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-600.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-600.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-600.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-600.svg#Poppins") format("svg");
  /* Legacy iOS */ }
/* poppins-700 - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-700.eot");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local("Poppins Bold"), local("Poppins-Bold"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-700.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-700.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-700.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-700.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-700.svg#Poppins") format("svg");
  /* Legacy iOS */ }
/* poppins-700italic - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-700italic.eot");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local("Poppins Bold Italic"), local("Poppins-BoldItalic"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-700italic.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-700italic.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-700italic.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-700italic.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-700italic.svg#Poppins") format("svg");
  /* Legacy iOS */ }
/* poppins-800 - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  src: url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-800.eot");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local("Poppins ExtraBold"), local("Poppins-ExtraBold"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-800.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-800.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-800.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-800.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-800.svg#Poppins") format("svg");
  /* Legacy iOS */ }
/* poppins-800italic - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 800;
  src: url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-800italic.eot");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local("Poppins ExtraBold Italic"), local("Poppins-ExtraBoldItalic"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-800italic.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-800italic.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-800italic.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-800italic.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-800italic.svg#Poppins") format("svg");
  /* Legacy iOS */ }
/* poppins-900 - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-900.eot");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local("Poppins Black"), local("Poppins-Black"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-900.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-900.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-900.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-900.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/poppins/poppins-v5-latin-900.svg#Poppins") format("svg");
  /* Legacy iOS */ }
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Muli';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("../fonts/muli/Muli-Regular.ttf");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */ }
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Muli';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  src: url("../fonts/muli/Muli-ExtraBold.ttf");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */ }
/* Montserrat-300 - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url("../fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Light.ttf");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */ }
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("../fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */ }
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("../fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Italic.ttf");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */ }
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: url("../fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Medium.ttf");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */ }
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: url("../fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */ }
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url("../fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.ttf");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */ }
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url("../fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-BoldItalic.ttf");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */ }
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: url("../fonts/montserrat/montserrat-v12-latin-900.ttf"), url("../fonts/montserrat/montserrat-v12-latin-900.eot") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/montserrat/montserrat-v12-latin-900.svg") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/montserrat/montserrat-v12-latin-900.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/montserrat/montserrat-v12-latin-900.woff2") format("truetype"); }
a:focus,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: all 300ms ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease 0s; }

input,
select,
textarea {
  outline: none;
  appearance: unset !important;
  -moz-appearance: unset !important;
  -webkit-appearance: unset !important;
  -o-appearance: unset !important;
  -ms-appearance: unset !important; }

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  appearance: none !important;
  -moz-appearance: none !important;
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  -o-appearance: none !important;
  -ms-appearance: none !important;
  margin: 0; }

input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  -o-box-shadow: none !important;
  -ms-box-shadow: none !important; }

input[type=checkbox] {
  appearance: checkbox !important;
  -moz-appearance: checkbox !important;
  -webkit-appearance: checkbox !important;
  -o-appearance: checkbox !important;
  -ms-appearance: checkbox !important; }

input[type=radio] {
  appearance: radio !important;
  -moz-appearance: radio !important;
  -webkit-appearance: radio !important;
  -o-appearance: radio !important;
  -ms-appearance: radio !important; }

input:-webkit-autofill {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px transparent inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px transparent inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px transparent inset;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px transparent inset;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px transparent inset;
  background-color: transparent !important; }

.clear {
  clear: both; }

h2 {
  font-size: 27px;
  color: #222;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: 'Muli';
  margin: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 65px; }
  h2 span {
    color: #e08f24; }

body {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #222;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  margin: 0px;
  background: #222; }

.main {
  padding: 50px 0; }

.container {
  width: 1400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #efeeff; }

p {
  margin: 0px; }

p.desc {
  padding-bottom: 330px;
  color: #999;
  line-height: 1.92; }

p.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 7px; }

.signup-img {
  padding-bottom: 43px; }

fieldset {
  border: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px; }

.signup-desc {
  background: #fff;
  width: 495px; }

.signup-desc-content {
  padding: 45px 55px; }

.signup-form-conent {
  width: 905px; }

.signup-form {
  padding: 55px 110px; }

input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s ease;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: transparent; }
  input + label {
    position: absolute;
    transition: 0.25s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.25s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.25s ease;
    -ms-transition: 0.25s ease;
    left: 0;
    top: 25px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #888; }
  input:focus + label {
    top: -7px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500; }
  input:valid + label {
    top: -7px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500; }

.form-group {
  position: relative; }

.field-icon {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -37px; }

.content {
  padding: 340px 0 315px 0;
  position: relative; }
  .content h3 {
    display: none; }

.step-current {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #f38749; }

.actions ul {
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -moz-justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  -o-justify-content: flex-end;
  -ms-justify-content: flex-end; }
  .actions ul .disabled {
    display: none; }
  .actions ul li {
    margin-left: 20px; }
    .actions ul li:first-child a {
      background: #fff;
      color: #999; }
    .actions ul li a {
      width: 140px;
      height: 50px;
      color: #fff;
      font-family: 'Montserrat';
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: bold;
      background: #d18f2c;
      align-items: center;
      -moz-align-items: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      -o-align-items: center;
      -ms-align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -moz-justify-content: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -o-justify-content: center;
      -ms-justify-content: center;
      text-decoration: none; }

.steps {
  display: none; }

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    max-width: 100%; }

  .signup-form {
    padding: 55px 30px; }

  .signup-desc {
    width: 465px; }

  .signup-img {
    width: 100%; } }
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .steps ul, .signup-content {
    flex-direction: column;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -o-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column; }

  .steps ul li, .signup-desc, .signup-form-conent {
    width: 100%; } }
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .actions ul li a {
    width: 100px; } }

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Text</title>

    <!-- Font Icon -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/material-icon/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">

    <!-- Main css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="main">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="signup-content">
                <div class="signup-desc">
                    <div class="signup-desc-content">
                        <h2><span>Text</span>Text Text</h2>
                        <p class="title">CText</p>
                        <p class="desc">
                        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
                        </p>
                        <img src="img/ban.png" alt="" class="signup-img">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="signup-form-conent">
                    <form method="POST" id="signup-form" class="signup-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <h3></h3>
                        <fieldset>
                            <span class="step-current">Paso 1 / 3</span>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="a" id="a" required/>
                                <label for="a">texttttt</label>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
    
                        <h3></h3>
                        <fieldset>
                            <span class="step-current">Paso 2 / 3</span>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="description" id="description" required/>
                                <label for="description">Descripci&oacute;n</label>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
    
                        <h3></h3>
                        <fieldset>
                            <span class="step-current">Paso 3 / 3</span>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="adjunto" id="adjunto" required/>
                                <label for="adjunto">texttttt</label>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>

                        <h3></h3>
                        <fieldset>
                            <span class="step-current">texttttt</span>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <h4>asadasd</h4><p id="s"></p>
                                <h4>asdasd&oacute;n</h4><p id="s"></p>
                                <h4>asdasd</h4><p id="s"></p>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
    
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jquery-validation/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-steps/1.1.0/jquery.steps.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hola @AngelusTech, al responder una pregunta, no nos podemos limitar a pegar el código y dejar que la persona que pregunte intente descifrarlo para poder entender donde estaba su error. Deberías de comentar cada parte del mismo, incidiendo en las que tenía errores o no supo continuar, despejando así todas sus dudas. Un saludo

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por la ayuda, soy nuevo aquí :)

Answer (score 0):

Ya quedó solucionado, el problema es que en en paso 4 se estaba validado algo que siempre regresaba falso, por eso no avanzaba al paso 5, se corrigió el proceso del paso 4 y ya avanzó al paso 5 sin problema